# Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName -Name "app" -Confirm:$false error in sharepoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

hi I am trying several ways to configure app url, but no luck, i am trying 1.started all services like app management service,managed meta data services,Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service Application,2.and giving full controls permissions

Answer (score 0):

Check that those service application are running by browsing them like this :

- http://[HOST]:[PORTNUMBER]/[PoolAppId]/SubscriptionSettings.svc for Subscription Settings Service Application
- http://[HOST]:[PORTNUMBER]/[PoolAppId]/AppMng.svc for App Management Service Application

because sometimes the Central Administration tells you that the services are running, but you find error logs in the event viewer saying something like the message below, to inform that your server needs more ressources to activate all services :

Error source : System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0
WebHost failed to process a request ....

Exception : System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: the service '/c720557bd2fa437c94391bd06bdb4d44/XXXXXX.svc' can't be activated due to an exception in the compilation phase.

If your server hasn't enough RAM memory, you can edit the web.config file of the desired service by modifying the  balise and including this one :

**`<serviceHostingEnvironment minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1"/>`**

hope this will help you !